# When should we use the ID of childs and groups in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

There is two methods in ExpandableListView?

```
getSelectedId()
    Gets the ID of the currently selected group or child.
getSelectedPosition()
    Gets the position of the currently selected group or child (along with its type).
```

We always use the getSelectedPosition. I'm curious about When we should use the getSeletedId? What can we do using the ID?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you will use CursorTreeAdapter (adapter based on the database) getSelectedId will return the id of the record in the database.